# Why cant the inner variable is being initialised with value when Button is clicked at runtime

Tags: android, inner-classes

Hello i am trying to get macAddress of my android device from webservice and is stored in database.But when the class is being complied the address space  is allocated during compilation and at runtime i am assigning value of some other string to this particular string on button click below is my class code.

```
package com.example.shashimishra.leaveapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import static android.util.Log.d;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  Button Userbut;
  Button Adminbut;
int id;String deviceID;
    String macId;
    DataBaseHandler handler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        handler = new DataBaseHandler(this);
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        deviceID = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
        init();
        init2();
    }
    public void init()
    {
        Userbut =(Button)findViewById(R.id.Userbut);

        Userbut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int count = handler.numberOfRows();
                Log:d("count ",String.valueOf(count));
                Cursor cursor = handler.getData();
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHandler.EMPLOYEE_COLUMN_ID)));
                Log.d("ID",String.valueOf(id));
                Log.d("DEVICEID",deviceID);
                Log.d("MACID",macId);
                new ReceiveMac().execute();
                if(count==0) {
                    Intent toy = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegistrationForm.class);
                    startActivity(toy);
                }
                else  if(!deviceID.equals(macId)){
                        handler.deletecontacts(id);
                        Intent toy = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegistrationForm.class);//if mac id is not equal registration page will be generated 
                        startActivity(toy);
                    }
                    else {
                        Intent toy = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Form_Activity.class);//else registration page will be skipped.
                        finish();
                        startActivity(toy);
                    }

            }
        });
    }

    public void init2()
    {
        Adminbut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Adminbut);

        Adminbut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent toy1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Admin_login.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(toy1);
            }
        });
    }


private class ReceiveMac extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {
        HttpHandler hh = new HttpHandler();
        String url =  "http://10.0.0.108:8080/WebServicewithMaven/rest/Employee/getMac?eid="+id;
        String jsonStr = hh.makeServiceCall(url);

        macId = jsonStr;

        return null;
    }

}





}
```

In above code jsonStr value(macAddress of this device stored in database) is coming from webserver onButton click and after that this jsonStr value is being assigned to another String class variable(macId). And this macId variable is being compared with deviceID which is generating macAddress of device.
But when i hit button.I get below error

```
D/count: 1
D/ID: 102
D/DEVICEID: 02:00:00:00:00:00
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.shashimishra.leaveapplication, PID: 5260
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                      at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
                      at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:143)
                      at com.example.shashimishra.leaveapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:50)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8613', transport: 'socket'
```

Can anyone provide me a better way to achieve my output.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should try to add an `onPostExecute()` and save the response from `makeServiceCall` there

Comment: Ahmed Abidi I tried doing what you said but still same error..

Comment: @AhmedAbidi thanks mate it worked perfectly..sorry for delayed comment.

Answer (score 0):

> Log.d("MACID",macId);

`macId` is not initialised and not assigned.

Isn't that line 50

> java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
>                         at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
>                         at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:143)
>                         at com.example.shashimishra.leaveapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:50)

you can try initialising `macId`,Strings in general, with a dummy value so you would know for sure they are assigned...  and
try `new ReceiveMac().execute();` before trying to log it in

Comment: I tried to do so but i have to fetch id from internal database of android so that i can send that id to the server to receive that id's macID.My page is comparing that if userinfo is in internal database that macid is received from server and then if macid equals then registration page will be skipped and if macid is not equal then apk will direct to registration page.

Comment: was that line not the reason for your crash?

Comment: Yeah i noticed that point and after that i corrected that point but even after that the same problem persisted in other words there were two same problem. I corrected the problem of initialisation but the problem existed. The coz of the problem was that on submit button hit doinbackground method was being called at last after rest of the process. So to get solution i wrote code in onPreExecute(); and the problem was solved.